# Docker does not follow symlinks within build directory

Tags: c, ubuntu, docker, clang, symlink

I am Dockerizing an application which involves linking binaries with other C files via Clang. We maintain a symlinked version of the binaries since they are used throughout the codebase. My Docker build directory contains this entire codebase (including the source files as well as the symlinks to those source files), and Docker recognizes those files when I do things like `cat [symlinked_file]` (i.e. the file is `cat`ed properly). However, it fails to link the symlinked files when I run my Clang commands in my Makefile (these work fine not in Docker). I then copied the originals into the directory where the symlinks are, replacing the symlinks, and Docker did not throw any errors on build.

Does anyone know how to get around this? Are there any special commands I need to give to Docker or Clang here? I am not sure why Clang is behaving differently inside a Docker container than outside of it. I am running from an Ubuntu 16.04 Base Image for reference.

Comment: Was the symlink _target_ within the build context directory, or in another folder on the filesystem?

Comment: Yes. The top-level directory `dir` where the Dockerfile is located contains subdirectories `dir1` and `dir2`. The symlinked files as well as the targets are located in `dir1`. I found the other question about files outside the build context and I can understand why Docker would fail in that scenario, but it confuses me why it fails when ALL the files necessary are in the build context.

Answer (score 8):

Docker will work with symlinks (at least when building on my linux host), but what it copies is the symlink itself, without following the link. Therefore you also need the the symlink **target** to be separately included in the build context and copied into the image. This context is sent over to the docker engine and the build occurs on that server within containers, so any link to files outside of that context will not resolve. You will also want these links to be relative, or the absolution path of a link must point to the same absolute path inside the image. Here's an example with relative links showing the difference between files inside and outside the context:

```
$ ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 bmitch bmitch 4096 Mar  2 21:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 bmitch bmitch 4096 Mar  2 21:07 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 bmitch bmitch   11 Mar  2 21:08 outside.txt -> ../test.out
lrwxrwxrwx  1 bmitch bmitch   10 Mar  2 21:08 source.txt -> target.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 bmitch bmitch    0 Mar  2 21:08 target.txt

$ cat Dockerfile
FROM busybox
COPY . /build-context
WORKDIR /build-context
CMD find .

$ docker build -t test-symlink .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.584 kB
Step 1/4 : FROM busybox
 ---> 7968321274dc
Step 2/4 : COPY . /build-context
 ---> 8238dac16669
Removing intermediate container dd653dfdf7a4
Step 3/4 : WORKDIR /build-context
 ---> c1850cb52f0e
Removing intermediate container 7ee87e20d525
Step 4/4 : CMD find .
 ---> Running in e710e965d98c
 ---> fd57eb8f426b
Removing intermediate container e710e965d98c
Successfully built fd57eb8f426b

$ docker run test-symlink
.
./outside.txt
./Dockerfile
./source.txt
./target.txt

$ docker run -it --rm test-symlink /bin/sh
/build-context # ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Mar  3 02:09 .
drwxr-xr-x   20 root     root          4096 Mar  3 02:09 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            69 Mar  3 02:08 Dockerfile
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            11 Mar  3 02:08 outside.txt -> ../test.out
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            10 Mar  3 02:08 source.txt -> target.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar  3 02:08 target.txt
/build-context # cat outside.txt
cat: can't open 'outside.txt': No such file or directory
/build-context # cat target.txt
/build-context # exit
```

Comment: Makes sense, but all of my targets are in the build context :(

Comment: @Rads docker doesn't follow the symlink, it copies the link itself as shown above. So I wouldn't expect copying a single link file to work since you didn't copy the target too. The windows filesystem is very different, I don't know if they even have symlinks at the filesystem level, or something different like a special file with a link filename, and data to parse. MacOS should behave like Linux but I don't have an environment to test the above commands.

Comment: @BMitch I've deleted my comment since it sounds too negative. Surely your answer is helpful to an extent. But I suggest you include the fact that docker engine is significantly different across operating systems. MacOS *DOES NOT* behave like Linux in many cases, maybe also because of distinguishing Docker Desktop vs Docker CE. Your comment above is inconsistent across operating systems. Docker follows the symlink and I've confirmed it and just like you, I don't have all environments to test either. Hence the large inconsistency.

Comment: @Rads the dockerd is running in a Linux VM on Desktop, so that half should be the same. However the docker cli (client talking to the engine) is running on the Mac or Win environment and it may see some differences. Rather than debugging in a comment, it's probably best to post an answer covering the platform you're working on, or post a different question on whether it's possible to get links working on your platform.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the exact same issue recently. After a lot of research and testing, here's what I found from the Docker team...

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1676

> Yes, we have chosen to not follow symlinks for docker build because of
>   the inconsistent results that could occur building on different
>   systems.

Basically, it's not a feature that's coming.

Here's the folder structure I had. Two repositories that sit at the same directory level.

```
/cms-code
/cms-themes
```

I wanted to symlink the `/public` folder inside `/cms-code` to the `/cms-themes` folder. And upon building a `Dockerfile` inside `/cms-code` to COPY or ADD the public folder into the image. Unfortunately, all I got was a symlink copied into the image/container, but not any contents.

**The Options as I see them:**

1. Create a bash/sh script to copy the files into public after both
   repositories are setup. [Not conducive to active development or
   refresh upon file changes]
2. Use Git's submodule system to move my
   `cms-themes` repo into the `/public` folder of the `/cms-code`
   repository. [Not practical for my particular situation]
3. Use `docker-compose` to set the `/public` folder in `/cms-code` to sync with my host `/cms-themes` directory. [This is ultimately what I
   chose. It's still not ideal, but it does work. The CMS container
   (once running) sees all the contents of `/public` which are actually
   the files in `/cms-themes`.

Hope this helps and is relevant to your situation. Let me know if you have any questions. I can share a sample `docker-compose.yml` file if you're unfamiliar with volumes in compose.

**UPDATE -- Adding compose file reference as Gist:**
https://gist.github.com/sgelliott/191c681ebb261c6a36ecd5fb70eb0176

Comment: If you could share a `docker-compose.yml` file that would be super helpful!

Comment: @AadilBhatti -- Sure thing... I updated my answer with that information. Hope that helps. Let me know if you have more questions.