# Can't cd into Softlink of directory in Docker Volume

Tags: docker

I use Docker Desktop run a container with a Volume(`/data`) to a directory in my macos.

[image]

Then I created a softlink:

in container `centos-test`'s `/data`, I can find it.

```
sh-4.4# ls -l
total 0
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72 May 25 03:30 ssl-cdn4-control -> /Users/jack/ScotchBox/my-project/public/ssl-proj/ssl-proj-control
```

you see the it link to my macos directory `/Users/jack/ScotchBox/my-project/public/ssl-proj/ssl-proj-control`.

but I can not access it, I can't cd into it with error:

```
sh-4.4# cd ssl-proj-control 
sh: cd: ssl-proj-control: No such file or directory
```

for proving in my macos Terminal I can `ls` it:

```
$ ls /Users/jack/ScotchBox/my-project/public/ssl-proj/ssl-proj-control
ssl-proj-control-backend    ssl-proj-control-frontend
```

Comment: That essentially is not going to work.
Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569303/docker-does-not-follow-symlinks-within-build-directory & https://superuser.com/questions/842642/how-to-make-a-symlinked-folder-appear-as-a-normal-folder.

Comment: thanks your response, but is there any way to copy data from macos to the container?

Comment: Sure, you can just not have it as a symlink the way you are currently doing it. Or use the COPY command in your Dockerfile.